# Need help in understanding Camera2Basic Sample from google

Tags: android, image-processing, graphics, camera, android-camera

I am following camera2basic sample from google, to learn about camera2 API.
I am struggling in understanding the following method , specifically the requirement of this method and what is it doing ,as its not properly documented.

```
   /**
 * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
 * This method should be called after the camera preview size is determined in
 * setUpCameraOutputs and also the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
 *
 * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
 * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
 */
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

here is the link to repo :- [Camera2BasicFragment.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java)

Answer (score 1):

I added 0º and 180º

```
@Override public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {

            configCamara(width, height);
            openCamera();
            previewRotation(width, height);
        }
private void previewRotation(int width, int height) {
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF textureRectF = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
        RectF previewRectF = new RectF(0, 0, previewSize.getHeight(), previewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = textureRectF.centerX();
        float centery = textureRectF.centerY();

        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            previewRectF.offset(centerX - previewRectF.centerX(), centery - previewRectF.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(textureRectF, previewRectF, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max((float) width / mTextureView.getWidth(), (float) height / mTextureView.getHeight());

            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centery, centerX);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centery);
        } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            matrix.postRotate(rotation, centerX, centery);
        }else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centery);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the device orientation is Surface.ROTATION_90 or Surface.ROTATION_270, there are two steps to construct the TextureView's transform:  scaling and rotating. In the Android demo's code, the first step is scaling, and the second step is rotating. It is very hard to understand.

I change the order of the two steps. In my code, the first step is rotating, and the second step is scaling.

```
private Matrix mTempMatrix = new Matrix();
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        //1. scale
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        //2. rotate
        RectF rotatedRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewHeight, viewWidth);
        rotatedRect.offset(centerX - rotatedRect.centerX(), centerY - rotatedRect.centerY());
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        mTempMatrix.setRectToRect(rotatedRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        matrix.postConcat(mTempMatrix);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
```